# Cannot understand the line from Apache Hadoop 3.1.0 documentation

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm reading the hadoop documentation and I'm unable to understand the line which describes replica placement ["HDFS’s placement policy is to put one replica on the local machine if the writer is on a datanode, otherwise on a random datanode"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9eVq.jpg). Can someone make me understand the line in the quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if a task is running on the same server as the datanode process, write the result locally. Otherwise, pick a datanode at random.

This could happen in the case where you have Hadoop processes running in Mesos or Spark Standalone clusters, where the datanodes are isolated storage servers, or there are dedicated YARN NodeManagers with large memory requirements, but not much disk space.

Second replica goes on the same rack, but a different datanode server, as that first replica.

Third replica goes elsewhere in the cluster, not on the same rack.

<sub>At least, that's how I learned it... The documentation seems to say the second and third are on the same remote rack... In any case, two replicas are on the same rack, the third being separate, in case of rack failure.</sub>